# Azure Pipeline: Run Azure command in PowerShell script got "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation", even run as the service connection

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, permission-denied, serviceconnection

I tried to run a powershell script as Service Connection. Given that all the parameters are correct, no powershell script syntax error. The Service connection is also the valid one as I normally use it successfully for other AzureCLI task. I am sure My Service connection can access to all the pipelines. there is no restriction to it that I am aware of.

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Run my script'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Service Connection'
    ScriptPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/drop/MyPowerShellScript.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: >
      -ADGroupName '${{ parameters.domainTeamName }}'
    FailOnStandardError: true
    azurePowerShellVersion: OtherVersion
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 6.5.0
    pwsh: true
```

and I got this error message when I run the pipeline
[image]

Here is the script code, the last line is where it failed. It cannot run that azure command *"Get AzADGroup"* because it does not have permission.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$ADGroupName
)

Set-StrictMode -Version 3

$ADGroup = Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName $ADGroupName
```

I feel weird because I have run the task as the valid "My Service Connection". it should have had permission to do everything. Anyone can help me please. Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that the service principal you're using has sufficient permissions to access Azure AD?

Comment: @DanielMann how can I check that ? When I created the service connection, I select scope level is my current subscription, and tick "Grant access permission to all pipelines". As I said there is no restriction that I am aware of. Normally I still can use it to run tasks that deploy other azure infrastructures: sql db, keyvault... it is all fine.

Comment: Look at the RBAC assigned to the service principal in the Azure portal.

Comment: @DanielMann , I navigate to Service Principle page, select "Role and administrators". I see that the service principle has "Cloud Application Administratior" role . The description of the role is "Can create and manage all aspects of app registrations and enterprise apps except App Proxy."  . Do I miss anything ?

Comment: Look at the duplicate questions about this. There are answers explaining a solution.

Comment: hi @DanielMann, I have take a look at those answers and it does not satisfy me. The first one require add more built-in roles (Directory.readers...) to the service principle. However I do not see any more role to add . There is only one built-in role "Cloud Application Administratior" . The UI seem to change already.

The second solution is not really passwordless solution.